# Will Home Assistant's face recognition data be stored permanently in the cloud?

Tags: privacy, home-assistant

Home Assistant v0.37 [includes face recognition](https://home-assistant.io/blog/2017/01/28/face-coffee-wink/):

> ### FACE RECOGNITION USING THE MICROSOFT FACE API
>
> @pvizeli has been on a roll with the image processing integrations. This time it’s the Microsoft Face API. This means that now it will be possible to train the API with the people you want to recognize and send images from your camera to the API as another source of automation.
>
> Want to play a personalized tune when someone enters the house? It is now possible.

This is apparently implemented by [integrating with the Microsoft Face API](https://home-assistant.io/components/microsoft_face/), which uses Microsoft's Azure cloud servers. To train the AI to recognise a person, you have to provide the name of the person to recognise and at least one image of them; after this, new images are sent to the API so that Microsoft's servers can process them and see if they match.

**Are these images sent via the API stored securely and deleted at an appropriate time, or does Microsoft keep the images forever? Can I remove the data at all, or does Home Assistant's facial recognition mean that images from my home are permanently stored in the cloud?**

Comment: What would you deem to be "an appropriate time"?  Does MS having nothing to say on the subject?

Comment: This seems more a question for Microsoft Azure (support team possibly) then HASS.